# Connecting to SQLite file with special characters in the file path

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine, escaping, uri

I have a unity application that uses SQLite to connect to some databases. I used the tutorial located [here](https://ornithoptergames.com/how-to-set-up-sqlite-for-unity/) using Mono.Data.Sqlite. 98% of the time: this works. However, in the case where the user has customized his steam game directory to include special characters: the SQLite connection fails.

Connecting via a connection string using either of the following works fine:

```
URI=file:C:/DB_TEMP/StupidName/main.db //works fine
Data Source=C:/DB_TEMP/StupidName/main.db //works fine
```

However, attempting to connect with the following:

```
string path = "C:/DB_TEMP/-=StupidName=-/main.db";
string connectionString = "URI=file:" + path;
SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

Throws the exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid ConnectionString format for parameter "URI"
```

I've attempted to use "data source" instead in hopes that it would not care about the special characters:

```
string path = "C:/DB_TEMP/-=StupidName=-/main.db";
string connectionString = "Data Source=" + path;
SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

But I get the same exception

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid ConnectionString format for parameter "Data Source"
```

I've tried various other things like constructing it via the Uri class:

```
string path = "C:/DB_TEMP/-=StupidName=-/main.db";
Uri uri = new System.Uri(path);
string connectionString = "URI=" + uri.AbsoluteUri;
SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

.. as well as attempting to encode the string with Uri.EscapeUriString(path), and directly attempting to escape possible offending characters:

```
string hyphen = Uri.EscapeDataString("-");
string equals = Uri.EscapeDataString("=");

string path = "C:/DB_TEMP/" + hyphen + equals + "StupidName" + equals + hyphen + "/main.db";
string connectionString = "Data Source=" + path;
SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
```

But to no avail.

What is the correct way to connect to a file with those special characters? Thanks.

Comment: Does this (C\#?) API require you to use URIs, or can it work with just a plain filename like the C interface?

Comment: @Shawn - sorry for the late response - no: you will get the same System.ArgumentException: Invalid ConnectionString format...

Comment: Same problem here, did you find something more out about that, @Jay-NicolasHackleman?